# Replace a line in a text file using windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have text file that has the following contents

```
status=y
```

I need to change it to

```
status=n
```

using a windows batch script

I tried this but I get a syntax error

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set INTEXTFILE=status.txt
set OUTTEXTFILE=t.txt
set SEARCHTEXT='status=y'
set REPLACETEXT='status=n'
set OUTPUTLINE=
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=" %%A in ( '"type %INTEXTFILE%"') do (
SET string=%%A
SET modified=!string:%SEARCHTEXT%=%REPLACETEXT%!
echo !modified! >> %OUTTEXTFILE%
)
del %INTEXTFILE%
rename %OUTTEXTFILE% %INTEXTFILE%
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of the text file? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Daemon I added the code I tried

Comment: Can you post a sample of the text file you are trying to modify? It is easier if we know what kind of content is has, why are single quotes in your code, ...

Answer (score 0):

Test this on a sample file.

```
@echo off
type status.txt|repl "status=y" "status=n" L >temp.tmp
move temp.tmp status.txt >nul
```

The above uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.